# Put a name on a certain number of rows

Tags: excel, count

Currently, I have a count next to the name of something for how often it occurs. With this information, I am hoping to put that name in that many rows with some formula. It would look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deNNI.png)

Comment: Please read through this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You will need a helper column.

In C1 put `0`.  Then in C2 put:

```
=B1+C1
```

And copy down at least one more row than rows in B with data:

[image]

Then in D1 put:

```
=IF(ROW(1:1)<=MAX(C:C),INDEX(A:A,MATCH(ROW(1:1)-1,C:C)),"")
```

And copy down till you get blanks

[image]